# Curl of a vector field

Tags: calculus

Let $w(r)$ be a vector field of the form $\vec w(\vec r)=f(\vec r)\vec r$ where $f(\vec r)$ is a continuously differentiable scalar field on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I need to compute $\nabla \times \vec w(\vec r)$.

I know I need to compute $$\begin{vmatrix} \hat x & \hat y & \hat z \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3
\end{vmatrix} $$

but I'm not sure what the $w_i$ are in order to do this.

Comment: $f(r)r$ is not a vector field, but a scalar field. You cannot take the curl of a scalar field.

Comment: $f(r)x$, $f(r)y$, $f(r)z$, where $f(r)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})$. The second $r$ should have had a vector symbol on it.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've edited the question, both $r$'s were supposed to be vectors.

Comment: OK, well, my answer stands; just interpret your $f(r)$ accordingly and use the product rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$w_1(\vec{r}) = f(\vec{r})r_1$, so
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r_1} w_1(\vec{r}) = r_1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_1} + f(\vec{r})
$$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r_2} w_1(\vec{r}) = r_1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_2}
$$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r_3} w_1(\vec{r}) = r_1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula of curl in spherical coordinates, and there is only the $r$ component, we have
$$\nabla\times\vec{w}=\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial w_r}{\partial \phi}\hat{\theta}-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial w_r}{\partial \theta}\hat{\phi}$$
$$=\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}r\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\hat{\theta}-\frac{1}{r}r\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\hat{\phi}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\hat{\theta}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\hat{\phi}$$